# Dumping data chunk by chunk while loading infinite page with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have successfully written a Python/Selenium piece of code that continuously loads an infinitely scrolling page. The full code is at http://pastebin.com/MaRkAWcg. It loads the entire raw html of the infinitely scrolling page as a large file, which I then parse with another piece of code. Obviously, if the scrolling page is huge (often is), there will be memory and CPU problems when loading and printing it.

So, does anyone know of any way to somehow load the html of the scrolling page gradually while at the same time appending it to a file, while dumping the data already appended from memory?

Comment: Why do you need to dump the page source? What are you going to do next? Thanks.

Comment: And, there is a twitter search there - why don't you use the twitter API instead of automating a browser?

Comment: @alecxe Next step is parsing the source with Beautiful Soup to bring it into csv format. Not using the API due to its strict limitations. Especially now that the full Twitter history is available through the web search.

Comment: Have you managed to find any solution to that? I am doing something quite similar and I am running into memory errors... Thanks!